# ORACLE splitting string with numbers to use into IN clause

Tags: oracle

I have a string field named CONCATENATEDFIELD in a table that returns the value '1,2,3'

I need to use this field right inside the IN clause:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE STRINGFIELD IN (CONCATENATEDFIELD)
```

I need this to work like:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE STRINGFIELD IN ('1','2','3')
```

How can I make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing the concanetaed string might be painful, since, one way or another, it will require some kind of recursion.

You could use a regex instead:

```
where regexp_like(
    concatenated_field,
    '(^|,)' || string_field || (,|$)
)
```

Or simply `like`:

```
where ',' || concatenated_field || ',' like '%,' || string_field || ',%'
```

Side note: [here is a recommended reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)...

Answer (score 0):

This `CONCATENATEDFIELD` is a string literal and can't be used with `IN` which expects a list of values (string values in your case).
Instead you can use the function [`INSTR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564):

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE 
WHERE INSTSR(',' || CONCATENATEDFIELD || ',', ',' || STRINGFIELD || ',', 1, 1) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr` to divide this values in to rows which can be used in `IN` clause as following:

```
Where stringfield in 
  (select regexp_substr(CONCATENATEDFIELD,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
   connect by regexp_substr(CONCATENATEDFIELD, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
```

Cheers!!